# Want to run multiple document upload and insert query at same time

Tags: php

I am generating multiple rows by clicking a button(2 textbox and 1 file upload option) in each generated row.
Result Expected : upload multiple document & insert file name in database.
Result Received : document upload done, query inserted but 2 times.
Code :

```
$o1=$_POST['V_Till'];//array
$o2=$_POST['D_Type'];//array
$countfiles = count($_FILES['uploadDoc']['name']);
foreach($o2 as $key => $val1) {
    if($o2[$key]=='') {

    }else{
        for($j=0;$j<$countfiles;$j++) {
            $filename = $_FILES['uploadDoc']['name'][$j];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadDoc']['tmp_name'][$j],'../uploadNot/'.$filename);
            $sql="INSERT INTO `doc` VALUES ('','".addslashes($i)."','".addslashes($o1[$key])."','".addslashes($o2[$key])."','".addslashes($filename)."','','')";
            if ($con->query($sql) == TRUE){

            }else{
                echo "Error:".$sql."<br>".$con->error;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show at least an example of the form(s)

Answer (score 0):

In previous code two loops are used that's why it runs 2 time. below code work well to upload file as well as inserting a query.
Updated code :

```
$countfiles = count($_FILES['uploadDoc']['name']);
for($j=0;$j<$countfiles;$j++)
{
    $filename = $_FILES['uploadDoc']['name'][$j];
    $o1=$_POST['V_Till'][$j];
    $o2=$_POST['D_Type'][$j];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadDoc']['tmp_name'][$j],'../uploadNot/'.$filename);
    $sql="INSERT INTO `doc` VALUES ('','".addslashes($i)."','".addslashes($o1)."','".addslashes($o2)."','".addslashes($filename)."','','')";

if ($con->query($sql) == TRUE)
{

}
else
{
 echo "Error:".$sql."<br>".$con->error;
}
}
```